# Remote script debugging output from exec()

Tags: php, windows

I try to debug a remote cli script on a Windows Server 2012/IIS installation. 
I have configured my ide to debug via http request. Everything is ok until I get to `exec()/shell_exec(), etc..` commands. I see no output in the debugger, though when launching scripts directly from the remote (via ssh/vpn) gives me the output that I expect.
Any workaround on this?

Answer (score 1):

Oh well, strange but this worked in my case:

1. Changed all my cmds to be enclosed in `'` but not in `"`
2. Always provide for exec all 3 params (output, status code)
3. For commands that don't need to be waited until the end used
   `pclose(popen($cmd, 'r'));`

Hope this will help anybody else here. Good luck!